# Message: Undefined offset: 1 in upload image

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am receiving an `offset` error but I am not able to find a solution for this, I am creating a function to send the images to my database and when clicking on send, this appears:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined offset: 1

Filename: admin/Properties.php

Line Number: 197

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\projetos\veloxmob\application\controllers\admin\Properties.php
Line: 197
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\projetos\veloxmob\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

And this is my code:

```
for($i=0; $i<$cpt; $i++)
    {     
        if (isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_FILES['upload_photo']))
        {       
            $_FILES['upload_photo']['name']= $files['upload_photo']['name'][$i];
            $_FILES['upload_photo']['type']= $files['upload_photo']['type'][$i];
            $_FILES['upload_photo']['tmp_name']= $files['upload_photo']['tmp_name'][$i];
            $_FILES['upload_photo']['error']= $files['upload_photo']['error'][$i];
            $_FILES['upload_photo']['size']= $files['upload_photo']['size'][$i];    
        }
        //$this->upload->initialize($this->set_upload_options());
        $this->upload->do_upload('upload_photo');
        $dataInfo[] = $this->upload->data();
    }
```

Comment: please show: admin/Properties.php

Line Number: 197

Comment: I am more interested in whole `var_dump($files['upload_photo'])`, as i don't see where `$files['upload_photo']` comes from. My guess is that the whole thing is not a three dimetional array.

Comment: $files['upload_photo'][$i]['name'];

Comment: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html check here @MKOT

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are overwriting `$_FILES['upload_photo']` in first iterate. choose a different key:

```
for($i=0; $i<$cpt; $i++)
{     
    if (isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_FILES['upload_photo']))
    {       
        $_FILES['upload']['name']= $files['upload_photo']['name'][$i];
        $_FILES['upload']['type']= $files['upload_photo']['type'][$i];
        $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name']= $files['upload_photo']['tmp_name'][$i];
        $_FILES['upload']['error']= $files['upload_photo']['error'][$i];
        $_FILES['upload']['size']= $files['upload_photo']['size'][$i];    
    }
    //$this->upload->initialize($this->set_upload_options());
    $this->upload->do_upload('upload');
    $dataInfo[] = $this->upload->data();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->load->library('upload');

        if (!empty($_FILES['upload_photo'])) {
            $files = $_FILES;
            $cpt = count($_FILES['upload_photo']['name']);
            for ($i = 0; $i < $cpt; $i++) {

                $_FILES['userfile']['name'] = $files['upload_photo']['name'][$i];
                $_FILES['userfile']['type'] = $files['upload_photo']['type'][$i];
                $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] = $files['upload_photo']['tmp_name'][$i];
                $_FILES['userfile']['error'] = $files['upload_photo']['error'][$i];
                $_FILES['userfile']['size'] = $files['upload_photo']['size'][$i];
                $config['file_name'] = 'upload_photo' . time();
                $this->upload->initialize($config);
                if ($this->upload->do_upload()) {
                    $result[] = $this->upload->data();

                }
            }
```